# why the setInterval method gets 10 as input variable?

Tags: javascript

my stopwatch with javascript and I don't get this point

```
buttonStart.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (Interval) {
  clearInterval(Interval); }
 Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);  });
```

Comment: 10 is the number of milliseconds between repetitions. Read the documentation.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp  That is a value in milliseconds.  It should execute every 10 milliseconds

Comment: Please provide reliable documentation ( w3school not being ). [MDN setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second value it receives is the number of milliseconds between repetitions. Meaning each 10 milliseconds it will run the `startTimer` function.